# Accessing an outside database while using apache

Tags: php, mysql, apache

I'm trying to adjust someone else's website. How can I access his database while testing code on a local apache set up? Here's what I think is the relevant code he's written:

```
define("INCLUDE_PATH", "/home/inter/public_html/toolmanager/includes/");
$this->default_mySQL_database="domain.com,xxxx,xxxx,xxxx";
...
$include=constant("INCLUDE_PATH").$path.$filename;
$handle = fopen($include, "r");
$data = fread($handle, filesize($include));
fclose($handle);
```

I'm getting this error at the fopen() line:

```
Warning: fopen(/home/inter/public_html/toolmanager/includes/platform/cache.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\toolmanager\toolmanager\includes\classloader_platform.php on line 401
```

For some reason it's still trying to access the localhost. I'm having a hard time understanding his code so let me know if there's something else I need to post.

Comment: Probably something in `$this->default_mySQL_database="domain.com,xxxx,xxxx,xxxx";`, but that's not a native PHP function so it's hard to say.

Comment: Check the include path set in your php.ini

Comment: @Mahn what should I set it to? Right now it's:           include_path = ".;C:\xampp\php\PEAR"

Comment: @CharlesMurray try include_path = ".;/home/inter/public_html/toolmanager/includes", and remove the INCLUDE_PATH define. Make sure classloader_platform.php can be found at that path too.

Comment: Also, it would seem your code is running in xampp, if you don't intend it to access localhost you should upload it to a (linux) server and access it from there.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this line control the database configuration

```
$this->default_mySQL_database="domain.com,xxxx,xxxx,xxxx";
```

You need to make sure however that the MySQL database server itself will accept connection for the specified user/password combination from your testing server location.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to enable remote access on the mysql database.
Here is a link on how you could achieve this : http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-do-i-enable-remote-access-to-mysql-database-server.html

Then once you have remote access, you'll be able to access the database from anywhere using the username you've created.

Answer (score 0):

The warning is not related to your db, but to the file you're trying to read. Indeed, your constant INCLUDE_PATH refers to a linux path, but your error shows us that you work on a windows machine.

if you want to get read of the error, adapt the constant INCLUDE_PATH, probably like this :

`<?php define('INLUDE_PATH', 'C:/xampp/htdocs/toolmanager/toolmanager/includes/');`

For the DB connection problem, mlishn is right : you should allow remote connections from mysql.

But you must also :

- create a remote user
- open the mysql port on the firewall
- configure your local app to connect with the remote user

Here is a tutorial that covers nearly everything: http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-do-i-enable-remote-access-to-mysql-database-server.html

But take care: opening a mysql Db over the web is **dangerous** !!

EDIT : added the modification proposal (based on the error, needs to be checked)